# Django get count of nested related object

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-2.2

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I have three models

```
class LeadList(SafeDeleteModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Lead List Name')

    def entries_count(self):
        return LeadListEntry.objects.filter(
            dynamic_url_object__lead_list=self
        ).count()
```

```
class DynamicUrlObject(SafeDeleteModel):
    lead_list = models.ForeignKey(
        LeadList,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
        related_name='dynamic_url_object'
    )
```

```
class LeadListEntry(models.Model):
    dynamic_url_object = models.ForeignKey(
        'otherapp.DynamicUrlObject',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='lead_list_entry'
    )
    data = models.TextField(help_text='Lead List entry data. (JSON data)', blank=False)
```

`LeadList` has reference in the `DynamicUrlObject`.
`LeadList` can be linked to multiple `DynamicUrlObject` instances.

The `LeadListEntry` is linked to `DynamicUrlObject` to record data for each `DynamicUrlObject` instance.

I want to get the **count** of `LeadListEntry` for particular `LeadList`.

For that I have a model method in the `LeadList` model to return the count of the `LeadListEntry` entries.

But on getting the list of `LeadList`, it is producing **N+1** problem where `entries_count` is called for each `lead_list` object which in turn runs a query on `LeadListEntry` to get the count.

I tried to use `prefetch_related` in the view like

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.serializer_class.Meta.model.objects.filter(
        user=self.request.user
    ).prefetch_related(
        'dynamic_url_object__lead_list_entry'
    )
```

But there is no benefit of it.

**How can I get the `count` for each `lead_list` object without running into `N+1` problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
ll = LeadList.objects.first()  # some lead list object

le_count = LeadListEntry.objects.filter(dynamic_url_object__lead_list=ll).count()
```

**EDIT**

You can use annotation like this.

```
from django.db.models import Count


ll = LeadList.objects.annotate(le_count=Count('dynamicurlobject__leadlistentry'))
```

Every object in `ll` queryset will have an attribute `le_count` containing total number of leadlistentries for that particular object.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing in the model method (mentioned in the question). This works fine for single object but with increase in number of `LeadList` records, the model method will be called for each object producing `n+1` problem.